# Unable to process csv file through jmeter listeners

Tags: jmeter

> I have performed load test using J meter non-GUI mode. Result file was stored in .csv format. Usually we extract this .csv file using a macro utility.

But now when i am trying to process this report using J meter listeners in GUI mode; i am getting error

> "Error loading results. see log file".

Not able to figure out reason for this. Any suggestions?

Also from where can i access this log file mentioned in error?

Comment: Log can be found in jmeter/bin folder and it is simply called jmeter.log. Check the info inside, can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Log file is located in the directory, from which you started jmeter. if you went to jmeter/bin and kicked off jmeter.sh (or similar), you will find it in jmeter/bin. If you kicked it off using relative path from other location, look for it there. This log file is really helpful - do not hesitate to check it.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you are uploading the CSV file place in J Meter folder & then
   upload to avoid error. Under Thread Group add CSV data config
   option. Her pass the File path in File name option.Also pass the
   parameters you want to change in Variables name field.